# Why would this function return a wrong value once in a while

Tags: python, django

I run a knitted sweater pattern producing website at Phrancko.com and I am mystified by **what is happening with this one function.**

I use this function to convert a user's "neck_circumference" to an adjusted value for "neck width."

```
def calc_width_from_neck_size(circ):
  with localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.prec = 3
    if isinstance(circ, Decimal):
      circ = float(circ)
    diameter = (round((circ / pi) * 8) / 8) + 1.375 # 1 3/8" wider than circular neck
    return Decimal(diameter)
```

It works consistently most of the time, but once in a great while returns a wrong value. When the user enters the neck circumference into a form, it simply calls this function and then places both the entered value and the result from this function into the database. No other processing occurs in between.

Here, for example, are all the results for users who entered 15.5 for neck width:

```
id,create_date,neck_width,neck_circumference

80,"2019-08-30 22:23:00",6.250,15.500
81,"2019-08-31 01:54:43",6.250,15.500
111,"2019-11-02 00:33:28",6.250,15.500
238,"2020-03-15 18:36:45",6.250,15.500
258,"2020-05-02 19:02:29",6.250,15.500
289,"2020-07-04 23:56:56",6.750,15.500
321,"2020-09-25 21:47:36",6.250,15.500
323,"2020-09-25 21:56:35",6.250,15.500
330,"2020-10-15 18:47:38",6.250,15.500
350,"2020-10-28 19:33:49",6.250,15.500
352,"2020-11-10 03:16:36",6.250,15.500
360,"2021-01-03 04:31:41",6.250,15.500
385,"2021-02-01 20:25:46",6.250,15.500
397,"2021-02-15 19:28:29",6.250,15.500
426,"2021-03-07 16:52:23",6.250,15.500
469,"2021-05-01 15:21:06",6.250,15.500
478,"2021-05-02 12:53:39",6.250,15.500
502,"2021-05-16 04:51:40",6.250,15.500
515,"2021-05-24 01:10:13",6.250,15.500
534,"2021-06-09 19:59:43",6.250,15.500
547,"2021-06-14 10:24:39",6.250,15.500
```

Note that the proper value 6.25 is stored most of the time, but then for id 289 it stored 6.75!

This was not the only time this happened. There are hundreds of records like this and only about 3 mistaken values. And they all occurred on different dates. As you see this one was on 2020-07-04. A different one was produced on 2021-05-22. The code did not change and change back on those two dates. This code has remained the same throughout the life of the website. I am completely baffled.

How could this function work perfectly most of the time but then on rare occasions produce the wrong value?

Additional information:

I can't supply an MRE because I can't produce one. Here is some test code that calls the function a million times and does not produce a single aberrant value.

```
from decimal import *
from math import pi


def calc_width_from_neck_size(circ):
  with localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.prec = 3
    if isinstance(circ, Decimal):
      circ = float(circ)
    diameter = (round((circ / pi) * 8) / 8) + 1.375 # 1 3/8" wider than circular neck
    return Decimal(diameter)

num_found = 0
for count in range(1, 1000000):
    circ = float(Decimal('15.000'))
    test = Decimal(6.125)
    width = calc_width_from_neck_size(circ)
    if width != test:
        num_found += 1
        print(f'WRONG: Count {count} Circ {circ} Width {width} round((circ / pi) * 8) {round((circ / pi) * 8)}')
print(f'Found {num_found} wrong ones.')
```

So then my attention turned to how the input value (circ) gets set. It is running in a Django view and here is the single line of code that calls it:

```
sweater.neck_width = calc_width_from_neck_size(sweater.who_for.neck_circumference)
```

The sweater.who_for_neck_circumference field is declared as follows:

```
class Recipient(models.Model):
  knitter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  recipient_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Their name:")
  chest_circumference = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
  neck_circumference = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
  shoulder_to_waist = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
```

The value is pulled directly from user input into this field after Django validates it and then passed directly to the function as you see above. I don't know what happens behind the scene in Django when the user inputs into a DecimalField, but I do know that when I extract it, the value is always a valid Decimal value which is passed directly to the function and the result is stored in a different field in the database. I can only see the aberrant behavior by doing a SQL display of all the fields that should be the same, as I indicated in the original question.

I can see why no one may be able to help me with this. I just don't know what else to do. I appreciate any suggestions as how to shed light on this.

Frank

Comment: I don't know what goes into the function, but could it be that the rounding step using `round((circ / pi) * 8)` causes the entire expression to evaluate to 6.750 instead of 6.250 for some inputs?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
Since you haven't posted complete code, nor done the expected tracing work, we have little way to help you.

Comment: Is it safe to assume this is python 3?

Comment: The [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function documentation warns that "The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising", but it does not account for such a difference.

Comment: Operations on `Decimal` are affected by the current context. Calling your function with a context that has different settings (eg different rounding rules) will/might yield different results.

Comment: Good point. I'll move the Decimal operations outside of the localcontext block and hope for the best in the future. I admit localcontext is also a bit of a mystery to me, but this was how I found to round to the nearest 1/8".